# What is the Latin name for the Romani people?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, names

The Romani (aka Gypsies, though some consider that a slur) are nomadic people who dispersed across Europe about a thousand years ago. In other languages they have exonyms like *tzigane*, *gitan*, and *bohème*, but "Romani" seems to be the preferred term nowadays.

But if one wanted to speak about them in Latin, what term should be used?

- *Romani* and *roma* are endonyms (names they use for themselves), but using *Romanus* seems overly confusing in Latin, since they don't come from Rome.
- *Bohème* can be back-derived to *Bohemi(c)us*, but they're not from Bohemia/the Czech Republic either.
- "Gypsy" and *gitan* both go back to *Aegypti(c)us*, but they're not from Egypt.
- *Tzigane* and its relatives come from Greek *ἀθίγγανος* "untouchable", which would give Latin *athinganus* or *intangibilis*, but I can't see that as anything other than insulting.

In Romanian they're called *Rromani* or *Rroma* to distinguish them from, well, Romanians. But starting a word with a double letter looks distinctly non-Latin to me.

Comment: `In Romanian they're called Rromani or Rroma...` - that is not accurate. The correct Romanian forms are "rom/romi" (Roma person, singular/plural), "rom/romă" (adjective, masculine/feminine; rarely, academic: "romani" ), hard to confuse them with *Romanian* (noun: român, româncă, adjective: român, română). But the English form *Romani* is closer to Romanian name of the country (România) and that has created a rather dubious (nationalistic) trend of double-r forms being *tolerated* in print in non-academic context. But that trend is marginal, as double-r is unheard of in Romanian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant entry in *Smith's Copious & Critical English-Latin* reads "gipsy: Cingarus, Zingarus, *f*. -a :after their Italian name *Zingari, The Gipsies*, *Aegypti qui feruntur."

That seems quite acceptable to me. However, since there is no classical precedent, I should think that you can please yourself on this. My own preferred word is *gitanus*, which in a very small poll that I once conducted was felt to be more readily recognised as 'gipsy', presumably because of familiarity with the brand *Gitanes* of French cigarettes.

[As an aside, there is a peripatetic cricket club in the UK and Australia, *I Zingari* so called because they have no home ground.]

Comment: Is that considered not offensive? I have no experience with this myself, but comparing to the list above *Zingarus* would seem to come from *athinganus*, which is why I'd held off on it.

Comment: @Draconis  I'm baffled. Which bit do you think might be offensive, and how?

Comment: I was considering *zingarus* potentially offensive because of its source. But it sounds like it's sufficiently detached from the source that it's considered neutral now.

Comment: @Draconis  As far as I know, the single, possibly offensive use of 'untouchable' is when it refers to the lowest Hindu caste (in Hindi the *harijan* championed by Mahatma Gandhi) or anyone not a Hindu, but it requires a deal of imagination to make it so.

Answer (score 1):

The Latin wikipedia uses [Zingari](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zingari) as generic term and offers a lot of more terms.

Comment: The use of _Zingari_ is not sourced by la.wp. But _Cingari_ is said to be in a dictionary of medieval Latin